# How to get array position from object name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have Array of objects:

```
arrDates = [{date:"03/28/2017", elId:0}, {date:"03/27/2017", elID:"newElement"}, {date:"03/27/2017", elId:1}, {date:"03/22/2017", elId:2}, {date:"03/16/2017", elId:3}, {date:"03/10/2017", elId:4}, {date:"08/02/2012", elId:5}, {date:"08/20/2008", elId:6}, {date:"08/18/2004", elId:7}, {date:"10/28/2003", elId:8}];
```

I'm wondering how I can access element with `elID`=newElement. When I access that element I want to find out position of that element in arrDates. Is that even possible without iterating over that array?

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid the clutter of a loop, this shorthand might do the trick: `arrDates.findIndex(x => x.elId === newElement)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is new technique to get the index of an object. This is available since 2016.

```
index = arrDates.findIndex(x => x.elID=="newElement");
```

Works fine and will return position of that element in the arrDates. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, `findIndex` isn't supported in IE (but Edge is ok), so keep that in mind for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are asking is how to do it without writing a long *for* loop?

```
arrDates = [{date:"03/28/2017", elId:0}, {date:"03/27/2017", elID:"newElement"}, {date:"03/27/2017", elId:1}, {date:"03/22/2017", elId:2}, {date:"03/16/2017", elId:3}, {date:"03/10/2017", elId:4}, {date:"08/02/2012", elId:5}, {date:"08/20/2008", elId:6}, {date:"08/18/2004", elId:7}, {date:"10/28/2003", elId:8}];
```

> This example will get you an array of items who's **elID** is *'newElement'*

```
var newElement = arrDates.filter(isNewElement);
// => [{date:"03/27/2017", elID:"newElement"}];


function isNewElement(element){
  return /newElement/.test(element.elID);
}
```

> You asked for the index, so this is the example for getting the index of the first item that matches *'newElement'*

```
var newElementIndex = arrDates.findIndex(isNewElement);
// => 1;
```

**Note**: 'findIndex' does not have support in IE, use *[PolyFill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=control)*

Answer (score 0):

The other answers using findIndex work well. So I'll do the work of using a loop, just in case you wanted that.

```
function myFindIndex(dateArray, id) {
  const arrLength = dateArray.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    if (dateArray[i].elId === id) return i;
  }
  return -1
}

findIndex(arrDates, 5) // => 6
findIndex(arrDates, 'abc') // => -1
```

You can generalize it a bit more by creating your own myFindByIndex that takes a callback function, then using it to create a more general function to find by id:

```
function myFindIndexWithCallback(arr, callback) {
  const arrLength = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    if (callback(arr[i])) return i
  }
  return -1
}

function findByElId(id) {
  return myFindIndexWithCallback(arrDates, function (arrElement) {
    return arrElement.elId === id;
  });
}

findByElId(5) // => 6
findBybElId('a') // => -1
```

And so you can keep on abstracting away. Eventually, assuming you don't want to use findIndex, you'll probably want to remove the hardcoded arrDates argument in the findByElId function too.